# Angular 2 Template Interpolation Escape Character Characters

Tags: escaping, angular2-template

I am an Angular 2 newb.

I'm trying to set a background-image of a div by interpolating the value of a string variable called bgImage that contains a valid url for an image.

However, I don't know how to get a pair of escaped double quotes inside of the parenthesis'

How do you escape characters in Angular 2 template interpolation?

This doesn't work:

```
[style]="'background-image: url(\"'+bgImage+'\");'"
```

or this:

```
[style]="'background-image: url(\''+bgImage+'\');'"
```

or even HTML entity codes do not work:

```
[style]="'background-image: url(&quot;'+bgImage+'&quot;);'"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind. I solved my problem with this:
    [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\''+bgImage+'\')'}"

Answer (score 1):

I had a syntax error. [ngStyle] needed to be used, not [style]:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\''+bgImage+'\')'}"
```